# Yepnope and "Proxy"-ing jQuery's ready() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I'm (very) slowly getting a massive static-file site up to date with all the latest goodies. I am using yepnope (packaged with the new Modernizr.load) to handle async dependency loading and I need it to, in the meantime, be backwardly compatible with the current codebase.

This requires that i either wrap every single jQuery call sitewide (too big of a task to do in the immediate future) in `yepnope()`'s wrapper, *or* the more creative solution is to *proxy* jQuery's `ready()` function through my own, and to delay the execution of any `$` code until the callback from yepnope is ready... jQuery's actual `ready()` function will be the handler once the yepnope test is satisfied with jQuery's ready. Make sense?

**The question at-hand:**

> Am I creating a disaster here? Is this
>   a suitable workaround for my
>   short-term issue of a poorly
>   implemented sitewide mess of spaghetti
>   DOM-centric code?

**update #3**

A more well-thought-out approach that also accounts for non-ready where anonymous function is just passed straight to jQuery. This is a third attempt at doing as little as possible to preserve just the functionality of `$(function(){})` calls as well as `$(document).ready()` calls.

```
    (function( window, undefined ) {
    var jQuery = (function(fn) {
    if (typeof fn === 'function') {
        yepnope({
            test: window.jQuery.length,
            complete: function() {
                fn();
            }
        });
    }
    var jQuery = 
        _jQuery = window.jQuery,
        _$ = window.$;
    jQuery = jQuery.prototype = {
        constructor: jQuery,
        ready: function( fn ) {
            yepnope({
                test: window.jQuery.length,
                complete: function() {
                    fn();
                }
            });
        }
    };
    return jQuery;
    });
    window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;
    })(window);
```

This is pretty sexy because while it duplicates the loading behavior of jQuery, it doesn't have a length, inherently... by using yepnope to test for `window.jQuery.length`, it will only return `true` once the **REAL** jQuery is loaded (the proxy doesn't have a `length`)!

I earnestly seek any criticism - especially from Alex Sexton :) lol

Comment: I believe this is as far as I can get on my own. At present, my main goal is to rewrite all code utilizing jQuery's `ready` to be wrapped with yepnope. Just trying to provide a drop-in phased approach to get some async goodness in right away.

Comment: Hi! I suppose, the only thing I'm confused about, is the case when jQuery wasn't available, wouldn't this just execute right away still? Perhaps you'd add in a `load` part or something, but as of right now, it always just calls `complete` and then executes. I think the best course of action for this would be to create a jsfiddle or a jsbin example. I'd be happy to pitch in some code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tried to use example of philwinkle, it doesn't work (at least resulting temp jQuery variable had .length prop in FF3.6).

Googled for a while and found [jQl, asynchronous jQuery loader](https://github.com/Cerdic/jQl), which have a way to cope with $(document).ready called before actual jQuery loading. Borrowed some code and got:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var jQ = {
    queue: [],
    ready: function (f) {
        if (typeof f=='function') {
            jQ.queue.push(f);
        }
        return jQ;
    },
    unq: function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < jQ.queue.length; i++) jQ.queue[i]();
        jQ.queue = null;
    }
};
if (typeof window.jQuery == 'undefined') { window.jQuery = window.$ = jQ.ready; }

yepnope({
    load: '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js',
    complete: function () {
        jQ.unq();
    }
});
</script>
```